# showing a div on scroll ONLY in a specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Putting simply, my home page is different than the other pages in one major thing, the header does not show up until you've scrolled 400px down. In any other page it shows on load and scrolling doesn't matter.

I wrote two pieces of code for each job but one is jQuery and the other in Plain JS. I need to combine them as they only should work based on the "home Page" condition and the y >= 400 condition.

This is what I have:

My home page has the "home" class added to it programmatically, so I can use this as a hook class.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //this hides the header until after slider has loaded on the homepage. Otherwise I get a glitch because the header attempts to load before the slider. So, I'm slowing it down only on the home page, else, timeout is Zero = show right away.    
    if ($("body").hasClass("home")){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('header').removeClass("hide-header");
        }, 5000);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('header').addClass("show-header");
        }, 0); 
    }    
});
```

This is the scrolling JS function. Because it's not conditional to the homepage, it's happening globally. I need to somehow combine these two so that this scrolling thing only happens in the homepage

```
//show header on scroll
topHeader = document.getElementById("masthead");

var myScrollFunc = function () {
    var y = window.scrollY;
    if (y >= 400) {
        topHeader.className = "site-header show-header"
    } else {        
        topHeader.className = "site-header hide-header"
    }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);
```

If it helps, here is the relevant HTML:

```
<body class="home page-template">
    <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
       <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">Skip to content</a>

       <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
          ....
       </header>
       .... blah blah blah
</body>
```

And the CSS for the classes you see there

```
.site-header{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}
.hide-header {
    opacity:0;
}
.show-header {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Did you try adding your eventlistener to the `if ($("body").hasClass("home"))` condition?

Comment: So...have you tried putting the second block inside the `if` from the first block?

Comment: Quite frankly guys, I thought JS and JQuery have different syntax for things like getElementbyID and stuff like that. I didn't think it would even work. Would it?

Comment: @litel That worked! I feel so dumb right now lol. By in all honesty, I'm not an expert in JS. Thanks a lot. You should put the answer in so that I accredit you and others that may stop by here can benefit from it as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);` inside the `if ($("body").hasClass("home"))` condition.